# What would be a regular expression that can test if a string is a valid Firebase key?

Tags: regex, firebase

I'm writing an application that allows users to input values that will be stored in Firebase as a key.

Firebase Key Requirement:

```
max size - 768 bytes
cannot contain . $ # [ ] / or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127
allows single spaces, but not double or more spaces
```

How can I express this as a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 1 byte = 1 character, and since you mention ASCII, assuming the valid characters are *ASCII characters 32 through 126*.

"Match any of these allowed characters, exactly 768 times":

```
[ !"%&'()*+\,\-\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}]{768}
```

https://regex101.com/r/lQ2gJ4/2

### Edit

That didn't work because I missed the need to block consecutive spaces. New suggestion, with a basic pattern of:

```
# a space, not followed by a space
# or a character not followed by a double-space.
# This pattern, matched n times, locking the start and end of the string.

^( (?! )|[a](?!  )){5}$
```

However, when I substitute the full character set in...

```
^( (?! )|[ !"%&'()*+\,\-\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}](?!  )){1,768}$

# it breaks Regex101, saying it's too large.
```

NB. It's much easier without RegEx:

```py
# Python example validator

def validate(s):
    valid_chars = 'abc123...'

    if not (0 < len(s) <= 768): return False
    if '  ' in s: return False
    for char in s: if char not in valid_chars: return False

    return True
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer.  Unfortunately this isn't quite there.  As it should accept strings of < 768, and regex.test(string) should return false if the string is over 768.  Fixing those two are easy mod to -> ^[...]{1,768}$.  The only thing left is to make it so it can accept " " (spaces) but not "   " (double or greater spaces).  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Ooh, I missed the main bit of the question with the limit on the number of consecutive spaces. hmm...

Comment: You could set `{768}` to `{1,768}` to cover a 1 to 768 times

Comment: Adding `^((?!\s{2}).)` to the beginning and `\s?` to the end will cover double spacing.

Comment: @JStevens that still comes back as a match when given a string with double spaces in it, in regex101 and in Python... and it allows a 769 character string that ends in a space.

Comment: I miss understood sorry.  Does the regex in use support lookahead?

Comment: I'm implementing the check with nodeJS, I'm pretty sure JS Regex Supports lookahead.  Thanks for your help with this @JStevens.

Comment: That is where I was going too... beat me to it... If you substitute 0-9 for listing out 0123456789 and the same with a-z and A-Z then [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lQ2gJ4/5) will not break...

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided a use case, and you may need more if this is a sever-side app with some complex inputs, but generally speaking, one isn't concerned about control characters in input since that would be someone tinkering about and trying to break things, and would be rejected accordingly by the SDK.

So the Firebase team [generally just focuses on the invalid, keyboard-producible characters](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/utils.js#L367):

```
// in JavaScript
function isValidKey(text) {
   return typeof text === 'string' && 
      text.length &&
      !text.match(/[.$\[\]#\/]/);
}
```

There are a couple exceptions:  `.value`, `.priority`, and `.info` are valid keys in Firebase, but only for accessing special meta data and not as a record id.

Side note: I don't see anything in the docs about double spaces.

[image: character constraints]